# Exception has occurred. _ClientSocketException (Connection refused)

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, api, dart

`your text`import 'package:apicalls/models/posts.dart';`your text`
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`your text`

class RemoteService {`your text`
Future<List?> getBoxes() async {`your text`
var client = http.Client();`your text`

```
var uri = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/boxes');`your text`

var response = await client.get(uri);`your text`

var json = response.body;`your text`

return boxesFromJson(json);`your text`

// return postsFromJson(json);`your text`
```

}`your text`
}`your text`

Was expecting this to bring the data from the API but the call is not bringing the details i need, connection is refusing.``` your text``your text ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing your code on a phone or emulator you can't use localhost (127.0.0.1) because it points to the phone's localhost, not your computer's. So, it just won't work.

I usually use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to run my API locally and connect to my device. Run the command `ngrok http http://127.0.0.1:3000` and the ngrok will return the Forwarding url. Now you just replace the old URL with the provided url. For example:

```
var uri = Uri.parse('FORWARDING_URL/api/boxes');

var response = await client.get(uri);

var json = response.body;

return boxesFromJson(json);
```